# Split an interface into two new interfaces without breaking the client code?

Tags: c#

I have an interface which reads/write Excel file and XML file and look like this :

```
interface IFileReader
{
   void ReadExcelFile(string filePath);
   void ReadXMLFile(string filePath);
   void WriteExcelFile();
   void WriteXMLFile();
}
```

How can I seperate the methods in this interface into two different interfaces without breaking the existing client code. new interfaces should look like this :

```
interface IExcelFileReader
{
   void ReadExcelFile(string filePath);
   void WriteExcelFile();
}

interface IXMLFileReader
{
   void ReadXMLFile(string filePath);
   void WriteXMLFile();
}
```

Comment: You can't if `IFileReader` is public. You can't know if they use it in their code.

Comment: Interface is a contract. And since it has been in use, this is the contract you can't break. If you change this interface, you will have to change all classes that inherit it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not - removal of methods from existing public interface is always breaking change.

You can discourage usage of the interface by marking it obsolete and at the same time implementing 2 sets of interfaces on your classes

```
[Obsolete]
interface IFileReader {...}

class MySuperReader : IFileReader, IExcelFileReader, IExcelFileReader
{
   void ReadExcelFile(string filePath) {...}
   void ReadXMLFile(string filePath) {...}
   void WriteExcelFile() {...}
   void WriteXMLFile() {...}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Alexei Levenkov has a good solution but that requires classes that already implement that interface to add the two new interfaces to their declaration. A less intrusive solution is:

```
interface IFileReader: IExcelFileReader, IXMLFileReader
{
}

interface IExcelFileReader
{
    void ReadExcelFile(string filePath);
    void WriteExcelFile();
}

interface IXMLFileReader
{
    void ReadXMLFile(string filePath);
    void WriteXMLFile();
}
```